# Method returns a dynamic array of structs in c#, I Can't consume its return value

Tags: c#, methods, dynamic-arrays

I'm trying to consume a DLL-located method in C#, which returns a dynamic array of structs. What ever I do, I receive the well-know "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error, Here is my last code and it still tells that error:

```
string v_user = "kish";

        string v_pass = "u";

        string v_number = "p";

        string v_address = "url has been replaced with this string";

        string v_cid = "abc";

        Cls_SMS.SMSReceive.STC_SMSReceive[] xts;

        Cls_SMS.SMSReceive px = new Cls_SMS.SMSReceive();

   // *** is the below line

        xts = px.ExtendReceiveSMS(v_user, v_pass, v_number, v_address, v_cid);

        int upper_bound = xts.GetUpperBound(0);

        for (int counter = 0; counter < upper_bound; counter++)

        {

            Response.Write(xts[counter].Message.ToString());

            Response.Write("<br>");

        }
```

please note that my main problem is about receiving a dynamic array of structs with struct type name (Cls_SMS.SMSReceive.STC_SMSReceive) and other aspects such as connecting to the remote server is not my problem. I just want to allocate a dynamic array of vendor-defined structs to the left side of the assignment opeator in *** line.

Please help me. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you define "dynamic array" in this context? what exactly does it return? A C# vector (`Foo[]`) is not a "dynamic array" if you mean growable.

Comment: What are you getting from the ExtendReceiveSMS?

Comment: @Jaime: I'm getting null value.

Comment: As noted in the comments discussion; the fact that I returns null rather than causing some kind of cast exception means the error is squarely in the 3rd party code.

Comment: We aren't the vendor; only they can offer a sensible answer here.

Comment: @Marc: I'm forced to use that because method's return type is an array of structs, but because the number of SMS's fetched is not determined, It needs to be dynamic so that It could fetch all SMS's the server has been received.

Comment: @Farshid - if that is re the "dynamic"; if the return type is `SomeType[]` then it is just an array; nothing dynamic about it.

Comment: I wonder then if the problem is simply: it hasn't got any data yet at that point. The way you describe it as incremental, maybe you're simply querying it too soon. Is there any kind of WaitForSomeData method?

Comment: No dear mark. Actually we're using that company's method for sending SMSs too and it works perfectly. The problem is all about receiving issues because of struct issues.

Comment: @Farshid - please please listen; I am **very** experienced in C# (including an MVP from Microsoft); this has **nothing** to do with the fact that it is an array of structs, and **everything** to do with he fact that the library method is returning `null`. *Why* it is returning null is a library issue. Only the library documentation or the vendor can answer that.

Comment: The fact that send works and recieve doesn't can simply mean there is either a *bug*, or just some missing configuration, for the receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear how the `px.ExtendReceiveSMS(v_user, v_pass, v_number, v_address, v_cid);` method assigns the array, it probably doesn't assign it at all because of the exception. Here's how you could assign a dynamic array and return it:

```
public STC_SMSReceive[] ExtendReceiveSMS()
{
    STC_SMSReceive[] result = new STC_SMSReceive[2];
    result[0] = new STC_SMSReceive();
    result[1] = new STC_SMSReceive();
    return result;
}
```

Also if it is dynamic you might also take a look at [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx):

```
public IList<STC_SMSReceive> ExtendReceiveSMS()
{
    IList<STC_SMSReceive> result = new List<STC_SMSReceive>();
    list.Add(new STC_SMSReceive());
    list.Add(new STC_SMSReceive());
    return result;
}
```

Comment: ExtendReceiveSMS is the method name I'm trying to consume. This method receives SMS messages from a remote server and for each SMS message it fetches, it returns a struct member of the array of structs. I need to define a dynamic array of STC_SMSReceive type (which is actually a struct type) and assign it to the result of the px.ExtendReceiveSMS method.

Comment: Also note that I dont have access to the definition of the method or the struct. I'm just consuming it.

Comment: @Farshid, OK, and when you step through your code in debug mode what does the `xts` variable contain after calling this method? Is `xts` null?

Comment: Well, then I guess you will have to read the documentation of the library you are using to see in which cases this method might return null and how to properly use it, or maybe contact the author of this method and ask him directly. That's something that's completely out of topic and no relation to your original question.

Comment: If xts of type STC_SMSReceive[] could fetch the result of the method, my all problems would be solved. Whatever I do, It just remains null.

Comment: @Farshid, as I said, that's a problem with the method you are using. So there are two possibilities: there's a bug in the method or you are not using it properly. You didn't mention anything about the library you are using so you cannot expect any help.

Comment: No, The vendor says it is OK for all of its costumers. I just need to define a dynamic array of structs and assign it to the return value of the method.

Comment: Vendors documentation just includes input and output parameters. :(

Comment: @Farshid, please understand that this is not our problem and we cannot help you with using some proprietary library. Only the vendor can help you.

Comment: Dear Darin, they do not give me time to show them the code. do you think "   Cls_SMS.SMSReceive.STC_SMSReceive[] xts;   " is wrong? I just want to prepare the array to give it to the method.

Comment: I don't ask about vendor-related issues sir. I just want to help on defining an array of structs.

Comment: @Farshid, no it's not wrong. It's perfectly valid C#. You are declaring the variable and later assigning its value to the method: `xts = px.ExtendReceiveSMS(v_user, v_pass, v_number, v_address, v_cid);` and it is this method that returns null. You don't ask about vendor specific issues but that's exactly what you are having here. In my answer I showed you how to define a dynamic array.

Comment: Thank you dear Darin. I'm digging more on this. Thanks my friend.

Comment: @Farshid, if the method is returning null then it doesn't matter what type you define to take the return value, you're not going to get anything useful out of it.  If the compiler's not complaining then the type of xts is probably correct.  Like Darin said, there's probably something wrong with the way you're using the method.   Either that, or there's a problem with the communication with the remote server.  Have you tried looking at the network traffic using Network Monitor, or something similar?

Comment: Dear Andrew, the compiler does not complain about the code even with a warning. I'm also sure about network access because I've checked. I'm just confused/

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the strict array; simply, the library method you are using is returning `null`.

There are various possibilities here:

- maybe returning `null` is an expected return value for some scenarios; check the documentation
- maybe you need some additional configuration, or maybe you need to call some additional method (`GetTheData()` would be too hopeful ;p), or wait for some other event before this data is available - check the documentation
- maybe it is simply a library bug; contact the vendor

If all 3 routes fail, *personally* I'd just open it reflector and look for a scenario that might return `null`. Then tell the vendor to fix the bug or clarify the documentation as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace your separate declaration of `xts` with:

```
var xts = px.ExtendReceiveSMS(v_user, v_pass, v_number, v_address, v_cid);
```

what type does Visual Studio now report `xts` to be?

You can tell by hovering over `xts` with your cursor and reading it off the tooltip.

Other than that if the vendor is reporting that it works for other users, you must have one (or more) of the arguments wrong. Ask the vendor for some example code that works so you can check to see if that connects to the server properly. If it does then the error is in the other arguments, if not then it's a problem with your connection to the server.